# Rename a file in Python

Tags: python, file-handling

I’m a self-taught python newbie of a couple of days. I’ve got a basic understanding of the way python operates, but I’m really stuck with the following.

I have a list of text files which are exchange server mail dumps of mailbox name. I’ve hundreds of these text files and they are currently in the name format `Priv_date.txt` eg `Priv_02JAN2004.txt`. I need to be able to tell what server they’ve come from so within these text files I want to read the 10 line which has actual mail server name (Server: MAILSERVER1) and add or append this to the original filename.

What I’d like to end up with are filenames that read `MAILSERVER1_PRIV_02JAN2004.txt`. I’m getting myself confused over what I can and can’t do to the filepath and name but can’t see what I’m doing wrong. I’ve got as far as this:

```
import os,sys

folder = "c://EDB_TEMP"

for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(folder):
    for filename in filenames:
        fullpath=os.path.join(root,filename)
        filename_split = os.path.splitext(fullpath)

        #print fullpath
        #print filename

        with open (fullpath, "r") as tempfile:
            for line in tempfile.readlines():
                if "Server:" in line:
                    os.rename(tempfile,+line[10:]+fullpath)
```

But I keep getting this error:

> error is TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works and does what you describe

```
#Also include Regular Expression module, re
import os,sys,re

#Set root to the folder you want to check
folder = "%PATH_TO_YOUR_FOLDER%"

#Walk through the folder checking all files
for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(folder):
    #For each file in the folder
    for filename in filenames:
        #Create blank strink for servername
        servername = ''
        #Get the full path to the file
        fullpath=os.path.join(root,filename)
        #Open the file as read only in tempfile
        with open (fullpath, "r") as tempfile:
            #Iterate through the lines in the file
            for line in tempfile.readlines():
                #Check if this line contains "Server: XXXXX"
                serverline= re.findall("Server: [a-zA-Z0-9]+", line)
                #If the line was found
                if serverline:
                    #Split the line around ": " and take second part as server name
                    sname = serverline[0].split(": ")
                    #Set servername variable so isn't lost outside scope of with block
                    servername = sname[1]
        #If a servername was found for that text file
        if len(servername) > 0:
            #Rename the file
            os.rename(fullpath,root+'\\'+servername+filename)
```

What this does is walk the directory, as you had before, finding each path. For each file, it will get the path to it, open the file and look for a line containing Server: SERVERNAME.  It will then extract SERVERNAME and put it into the servername variable.  When the file is finished, it will be closed and the script checks if that file produced a servername string.  If it did, it renames the file by prefixing with SERVERNAME.

I had some time so decided to test it too so should do what you want

Comment: Thanks for the input so far.  I can see what I’ve missed in my original post. I’ve been looking at the code you’ve added o0rebelious0o (thanks!) I’ve worked through it so it makes sense to me, but I still get an error:[Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Dunno why. I’ve used Proc Explorer and checked start unlocker , I’ve even tried adding a new path to the root variable so the rename should take place in a different directory, but nothing seems to make a difference. I’m using a windows 7x64 bit os.

Comment: The reason it is giving you that error is because you are trying to rename the file inside the while file is open block.  While the file is open, the OS has a lock on it so it cannot be renamed.  With python it is important to note that indented blocks are treated the same way a braced code {} in languages such as java and C.  all code indented is executed under the same condition i.e in the with statement.  All you should need to do is bring the if len() statement inline with the with open statement and it should in theory work.  Also check that the process creating the.txt logs isnt running

Comment: Thanks again. That makes sense. I'm probably asking for the moon on a stick here..in python :-)..but I'm now getting an Error 123 filename,directory,volume is incorrect. I've done a print of the final line and it (or maybe it's me) seems to be putting an eol character in the line, so the output looks like MAILSERVER\nPRIV_02JAN2004.txt. I can't see why.

Comment: If I put the backslashes the opposite way '//'+servername+filename, I don't get an EOL line character in the line, but still get the Error 123 syntax in incorrect.

Comment: is it possible that sname is keeping a carriage return after the value? in Idle, entering sname and hitting return gives 'MAILSERVER1\n'..or is that \n because I've just hit enter? Very sorry for the newbie lack of knowledge.

Comment: Ahh. Lightbulb! servername=sname.strip() does the job. Thanks very much for your help all, esp. o0rebelious0o.

Answer (score 3):

You have an error in your `os.rename(tempfile,+line[10:]+fullpath)`  the comma seem misplaced.

The error basically says the `+` just after the comma cannot precede a string, which is line[10:].

Comment: This. OP: You should use an editor that'll point out obvious errors like this for you, like Vim+Synstastic, Gedit+plugins or even an IDE. It'll save you a lot of time.